# ZendFramework Contact Query

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-contacts-api

I am using the following

```
  // perform query and get feed of all results
  $query = new Zend_Gdata_Query(
    'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full');
  $query->maxResults = 1000;
  $query->setParam('sortorder', 'descending');
  $feed = $gdata->getFeed($query);
```

To retrieve a specific user's contacts.
However I want this to be ordered by name, how is this possible? I was trying something like this however it does not seem to work.

```
      $query->setParam('orderby', 'name');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I actually am getting a 401 error with that URL, but assuming it worked you would have to check with google to see what params can be sent - if any - to sort the results by a certain criteria.  The setParam() function you're seeing is merely setting GET params such that the actual full URL being sent to google is this:

http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=1000&sortorder=descending

All you need to do is find out from Google the correct parameter name to set the "sort by" field.

Comment: and consequently, this the full URL if you're using $query->setParam('orderby', 'name');
 like you had put: http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=1000&sortorder=descending&orderby=name